# Ambiguity in Unicode Syntax XlsxWriter Python 2 Module

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

I am working now with python 2.7.6 and using XslxWriter module for writing some data to a excel file. I have some unicode data that store in a list. When i try to use the instructions according to the documentation to saving the data to the file i have some troubles.
The instruction found that [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_unicode_python2.html?highlight=unicode)

The instruction says when you want use the module with unicode string and python 2 you must type *u* in the first of string! I'm try with simple string such as *محسن* .The result is good.

but my data is in a list when i try to do this, interpreter try to recognise it as a variable with a new name such as *ufoo*. When space disconnect those, interpreter recognise *u* as a unknown variable(also try to concatenate with *+* this problem occured)
I'm a little bit confused. Is there anyway to solve this ambiguity?

thanks for your help.

Comment: The `u''` is used for string literals. For string variables you will probably need to encode them with something like: `string = string.encode('utf-8')`. Also, you should add a small example of what you are trying to do. It would help people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I use the function decode.

```
tip = 'Haz clic aquí para acceder al fichero remoto.'
tip = tip.decode('utf-8')
```

One example to use decode in python 2

```
import xlsxwriter

# Create a new workbook and add a worksheet
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hyperlink.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Hyperlinks')

# Format the first column
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 30)

# Add the standard url link format.
url_format = workbook.add_format({
        'font_color': 'blue',
        'underline':  1
})

# Add a sample alternative link format.
red_format = workbook.add_format({
        'font_color': 'red',
        'bold':       1,
        'underline':  1,
        'font_size':  12,
})

# Add an alternate description string to the URL.
string = 'Grabación'
string = string.decode('utf-8')

# Add a "tool tip" to the URL.
tip = 'Haz clic aquí para acceder al fichero remoto.'
tip = tip.decode('utf-8')

# Write some hyperlinks
worksheet.write_url('A15', 'external://ordenador-remoto/Directorio/fichero.wav', red_format, string, tip)

workbook.close()
```